# CSS grid-template responsiveness

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

So I'm testing CSS's `grid` abilities and one of the things I can't figure out is zooming levels from browsers and the behavior of images within them.

e.g. If I change the viewport it's all fine. The grid and it's images scales perfectly but there are users who use `ctrl`+`-` or `cmd`+`-`.

If this is used the image is scaled like it should but the grid doesn't scale like I thought it would.

I created a basic grid containing 4 columns and no rows. I don't want to have the width full screen so I added a margin on the container holding the grid of 25%.

The grid is place within the center. Here is a Fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/kagprzae/

Can anyone see where I missed a turn?

---- SEMI-SOLVED IT----

So The trick is to use absolute pixels. That way you can use `ctrl/cmd`+`-`

The downside is that the grid isn't responsive anymore so you have to use `@media` queries to change layout...

I'm not sure what I believe would be the best approach to do this.

---- COMPLETE SOLUTION NO JS ----

So after some (a lot) of testing and thinking I came up with the following solution.

Give the `.container` a width (in my case I could) and calculate your grid according to a 100% width.

You can `margin:0 auto;` to center the `div`.

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fa6263k2/)

Comment: I don't really see any difference between changing the width of the fiddle output and zooming in and out. What do you see happening?

Comment: If you zoom in you see that the width of the grid stays the same and won't be zooming accordingly...

Comment: Oh wait. Zooming in a desktop browser does not change the viewport size. You were expecting a horizontal scrollbar to appear I presume? That's not how zooming works. You _can_ however, simulate the behaviour you expect by giving the `body` a specific width in pixels. Say, `600px` or something. Don't do this in a production environment though.

Comment: No I wasn't expecting a horizontal scrollbar to appear. The problem is that while zooming the width of the grid doesn't get smaller while the rest is. If you scale the viewport the grid get's smaller.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still not sure what you expect. The `.container` has 25% margins, so its net width is half of the viewport. No matter the size of the viewport or the zoom factor. Can you make a mocked up screenshot of what you want it to look like when zoomed in?

Comment: Okay let me try one more time. Sorry if my explaining is unclear to you. The problem is that the grid's width is bound to the viewport-size. If I use `crtl/cmd`+`-` the content decreases in size but the viewport stays the same. The height of the rows isn't set so the height decreases but the width remains because the content is changing and not the viewport. So what I want is to decrease the viewport-size if a user uses `ctrl/cmd`+`-`

Comment: If I would answer that, my answer would be the same as my second comment. Like I said, you can simulate it by setting the body width explicitly. Here is an [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/kagprzae/1/) that does it with JavaScript.

Comment: Okay then I don't understand your second comment. However this does work and it's beautiful. Thank you

Comment: Note that it only works properly if you start up the page when the zoom factor is 100%!

Comment: Yeah I noticed that too. You don't want to hit refresh after you downsized it....

Comment: @MrLister Please see my updated answer with a no `js` solution